# How to get the values of multiple checkboxes in typescript file using angular 6?

Tags: html, angular, angular6

I have 8 to 10 checkboxes in my html. I need to send the checked checkboxes values to my typescript file.

```
<div>
    <input type="checkbox" value="one" id="one" name="num">
    <input type="checkbox" value="two" id="two" name="num">
    <input type="checkbox" value="three" id="three" name="num">
    <input type="checkbox" value="four" id="four" name="num">
</div>
```

How do I get all the selected checkboxes values in my ts file? Can somebody help me with this?

Comment: Are you using `Reactive forms` or `Template driven forms`, in your code nothing is there!!!

Comment: @Javascript Lover - SKT I'm using Reactive forms

Answer (score 1):

You could use an array containing informations on your checkboxes, `ngFor` loop and `ngModel`:

```js
checkboxes = [
    {
      value: 'one',
      selected: false
    },
    {
      value: 'two',
      selected: false
    },
    {
      value: 'three',
      selected: false
    },
    {
      value: 'four',
      selected: false
    }
  ]
```

Your html :

```html
<div>
    <input *ngFor="let ch of checkboxes" [(ngModel)]="ch.selected" type="checkbox" value={{ch.value}} id={{ch.value}}  name="num">
</div>

<button (click)="getSelected()">Print selected checkboxes</button>
```

And the `getSelected()` function:

```js
public getSelected() {
    let result = this.checkboxes.filter((ch) => { return ch.selected })
                     .map((ch) => { return ch.value });
    console.log(result);
}
```